# How to get expression evaluation warnings from Angular

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to tell angular to show some Error or Warning about failed expressions? especially missing methods?

The reason I am asking this is that quite often angular would just break with no explanation, the reason could be that you have some object on the scope that used to have a `getAllItems()` method and someone decided to change it to `getItems()`.

It would be very helpful if there was a way to get some form of a report that says that some expression e.g. `user.messages.getAllItems().length` failed to evaluate/parse/whatever because `null has no length property` or if they can say because `user.messsages` does not have a getAllItems method...

I am well aware that it is by design that angular expressions fail silently, but a way to get a report of said silent failures could prove to be very valuable.